# Why $d^{10}$ metals follow the free electron approx better than the other metals

Tags: conductors, electronic-band-theory, kinetic-theory

The [free electron gas model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) is surprisingly good at explaining the properties of the conduction electrons in metals, but it works better in some metals than others. In particular it works well for Au, Ag and Pt and less well for transition metals.

I note that these metals have a $s^1d^{10}$ or $s^0d^{10}$ electronic configuration. Is this related to the effectiveness of the free electron model, or if not is there any other simple way of relating the effectiveness of the model to the electronic configuration?